# How to make links in a QWizard's subtitle clickable?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qwizard

I am constructing a little wizard following Qt's `classwizard` example.

Now I set the subTitle of my `QWizard` instance to some html text that includes a link.
I know about `QLabel.setOpenExternalLinks(True)` but how do I achieve the same effect with a `QWizard`'s `subTitle`?

I looked at `QWizardOptions` but there is nothing there.

Please take a look at the following image:

[image: http://imgur.com/zr3ILq2]

I want to make www.plugincafe.com open in the default browser.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT: I am already calling `self.setSubTitleFormat(1)` where `self` is the `QWizard` instance and 1 is the enum value for `Qt::RichText` because I don't know how to get the proper enum constant in PyQt.

I tried all possible 4 enum values but other than text styling or no it didn't change anything.

The string value with the embedded HTML is `'Obtain a unique ID from <a href="http://www.plugincafe.com">www.plugincafe.com</a> or use <font color="maroon">%s</font> for testing purposes.' % PLUGIN_ID_TESTING`

Comment: Set subTitleFormat(Qt::RichText) and set corresponding HTML to setSubTitle.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I should have mentioned a google search led me to this suggestion earlier but I forgot to include it in my original question. Other than changing the text style it doesn't seem to do much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QWizard (and QWizardPage) only expose mimimal control over the QLabel used as subtitle, but you can just iterate through all child QLabels in your QWizard and call `setOpenExternalLinks(True)`:

```
for label in wizard.findChildren(QLabel):
    label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
```

If you don't want to set it on all labels, then you need to check if you found the correct one.